# unable to insert into database using msqli_query

Tags: php, mysql

I am retreiving the contents form an array and adding them in to the variables.(The variables are not empty, I have checked using echo). I am trying to return success in JSON if my contents are added into the database but im unable to do so.I am getting the result as false.

The $con is created correctly and is also working perfectly for a "select" query on this connection just before this part of code displayed below.I have added the $con statement below just for better understanding.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die(mysql_error());
$id=$record["id"];
$caller=$record["caller"];
$receiver=$record["receiver"];
$mapurl=$record["mapurl"];
$timestamp=$record["timestamp"];
$res=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO call (id,caller,receiver,mapurl,timestamp) VALUES  ('$id','$caller','$receiver','$mapurl','$timestamp')");
if ($res) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Added the Values in the Database";
echo json_encode($response); 
}
else{
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Insert Not Successful";
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

My Output :

```
{"success":0,"message":"Insert Not Successful"}
```

My Database Structure :

(I am unable to post the image here as i have low reputation and one needs 10 reputation to do so)

```
MySQL
Table name: call

Columns - Datatypes
id - int(255)
caller - text
receiver - text
mapurl - text
timestamp - text
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating table names that are reserved words/keywords in MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695578/creating-table-names-that-are-reserved-words-keywords-in-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call` is a MySQL reserved word

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

either name it to something else or wrap it in ticks

```
INSERT INTO `call` ...
```

using `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` would have signaled an error.

A quick FYI: `call` is a word which is used for stored procedures:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/call.html

*"The CALL statement invokes a stored procedure that was defined previously with CREATE PROCEDURE."*

which is why you should be using ticks around the table name, or name it to "calls".

**Sidenote:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only a typo, you wrote: `$timpestamp=$record["timestamp"];` instead of $timestamp
and as Fred -ii- said, call is a MySQL reserved word.

Comment: I'm thinking OP may be taking `$record` somewhere that hasn't posted, in how it's being populated. Notice how they all start with `$record`.