# Error when trying to insert into MS Access Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

I am developing a program that uses a relational database. In one particular form I am trying to insert new products information into the database.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

When I try to save a new product this code runs...

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string query = "insert into Products (ProductName,ProductSKU,RP,WP,Stock,FPS,Ammo,MagazineCap,HopUp,Range,Brand,Colour,Action,Features) values('" + txt_ProductName.Text + "','" + txt_SKU.Text + "'," + txt_RP.Text + "," + txt_WP.Text + "," + numericUpDown_Inventory.Value + "," + cobo_FPS.Text + ",'" + cobo_Ammo.Text + "'," + cobo_MagazineCap.Text + ",'" + cobo_HopUp.Text + "'," + cobo_Range.Text + ",'" + cobo_Brand.Text + "','" + cobo_Colour.Text + "','" + cobo_Action.Text + "','" + txt_Features.Text + "')";
//Action field currently causes an error
MessageBox.Show(query);
command.CommandText = query;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

...and an error is thrown

> "Error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in
>   INSERT INTO statement."

(and then a bunch of stuff which I don't think is important)

Apologies for the HUGE SQL query. I am using the exact same method of using the insert SQL query in several other places in my program and they all work completely fine. This example however is causing this error. Through the tedious process of "commenting out" individual parts of my SQL query I found that the error lies with the "Action" field. I have checked that the data type in my database is correct and that I am using the '' punctuation to surround the text string that is being inserted into the database.

I think I've checked everything, so why am I still getting this error?

Many thanks in advance and if more information is required just let me know ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Action` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266?wa=wsignin1.0) in OLE DB Provider. You need to use it with square brackets like `[Action]`. [As a best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695578/creating-table-names-that-are-reserved-words-keywords-in-ms-sql-server), change it to *non-reserved* word.

### But more impontant

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` automatically instead of calling `.Close()` method manually.

Comment: Many thanks @Soner Gönül for you help. I've got it working but I shall take a look at the wonderful parameterized queries you've opened my eyes to!