# UPDATE string with an apostrophe in the string

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am working on a C# windows form which is connected to MySQL and updates strings within the form. I have everything working properly except for a small issue.

Say you want to update the "notes" field to read "The dog's bone", that apostrophe is causing the SQL query to end and cause an error. How can I get around this please?

```
UPDATE `database`
SET `notes` = 'The dog's bone'
WHERE `Pet` = 'Dog';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add another single quote before the apostrophe   or add a Salah

Answer (score 6):

You can [escape `'` character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql) in MySQL with doubling it like `''`.

Other than that, if you use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/), you will not need this *at all*. Just pass your `The dog's bone` string directly to your parameterized query and you will be fine.

Also I *strongly* suspect you try to use `UPDATE` instead of `SELECT` statement. In MySQL, [`SELECT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) doesn't have any `SET` part.

And using [a reserved keyword as a column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695578/creating-table-names-that-are-reserved-words-keywords-in-ms-sql-server) is a bad idea. As a best practice, change your `database` column name to *non*-reserved word.

```
using(var con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE `database` SET notes = @notes
                        WHERE Pet = @pet";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", "The dog's bone");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pet", "Dog");

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I used `AddWithValue` method as an example in my code since I didn't know your column types but **you don't use it**. [This method *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Answer (score 2):

Escape it with another single quote `'`:

```
SELECT `database`
SET `notes` = 'The dog''s bone'
WHERE `Pet` = 'Dog';
```

Comment: Thank you sir, do you have any idea how to do it programmatically?

Comment: I recommend you to follow sonor Gönüls advice to use parameterized queries.