# Syntax error near Desc SQL , error shows on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to issue an Insert statement in C# for an Accounting Application and i stumble into some problems which says it has an Error on Line 88 Which happens to fall here

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        cn.Open();
        if (choice.Text == "DEPOSIT")
        {
            double newAccBal = Convert.ToDouble(opening_amount.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(amount.Text);
            string newBal = newAccBal.ToString();
            string sql = "insert into credit (fullname,accountNo,opening_amount,amount,desc,newBal) values (@fullname,@accountNo,@opening_amount,@amount,@desc,@newBal)";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", fullname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountNo", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opening_amount", opening_amount.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amount.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", desc.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newBal", newBal);

                try
                {
                    var msg = MessageBox.Show("Information to be Sent for Deposit" + Environment.NewLine + "Please Confirm to Continue?", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                    if (msg == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); <------------------------------ This Area
                        string confirmation = "Full Name : '"+fullname.Text+"' "+Environment.NewLine+" Depositing Amount : '"+amount.Text+"' "+Environment.NewLine+" Description : '"+desc.Text+"' "+Environment.NewLine+" New Balance : '"+newBal+"'";
                        MessageBox.Show("Deposit Successful" + Environment.NewLine + "Information has been Saved for Records" + Environment.NewLine + "Confirmation is as follows" + Environment.NewLine + confirmation ,"Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }

                    string sql2 = "update account_info set opening_amount = '"+newBal+"' where id='"+id.Text+"'";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, cn))
                    {
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

says Incorrect syntax near desc and points at that line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` , what am i missing?

Comment: `desc` is a keyword use `[desc]` instead or choose another name for the column

Comment: @un-lucky, Thanks and May God bless you. Works 100%

Comment: Well, you can mark any one of the elaborated version of this comment as accepted answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating table names that are reserved words/keywords in MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695578/creating-table-names-that-are-reserved-words-keywords-in-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESC is a reserved word in SQL, short for descending and used in ORDER BY clauses. Wrap it in square brackets in your SQL statement.

Comment: Nothing more than a comment

Answer (score 0):

You named one of your columns `desc`. However, that is a [reserved word](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.110).aspx). You will either have to pick a different column name (might be a smart choice) or use a way to make sure your DBMS recognizes you mean your column, not the reserved word. You can use `[`and `]` to annotate names: `[desc]` should work.