# C# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.'

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I create a table named Table with members (first name, last name, address). The program is throwing the error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'". The application is to insert the data into the table. The code is for the new button exception handler.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Week4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\cvyc8\Documents\Testing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Member] values ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "', '" + txtAddress.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Member added successfully");
        }

        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `[Table]` and Sql Injection and you have extra `)`

Comment: I see you updated your table name from 'table' to '[member]'. If you are still getting the exact same error message which says keyword 'table' then you are not running your new code.

Comment: @TomC, new error, Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.'

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and stepping through. The message is explicit and says 'table', so you are NOT running the commandtext you think you are.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parameters  to avoid sql injection

```
string sql = "insert into Member(col1, col2, col3) values(@val1, @val2, @val3)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\cvyc8\Documents\Testing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
{
  connection.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
  {
     md.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = txtFirstName.Text;  
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@val2", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value =  txtLastName.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@val3", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = txtAddress.Text;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
     MessageBox.Show("Member added successfully");
}
```

Comment: Call my connection info twice? I call it in the From1 Class.

Comment: @CVYCCVYC no need to call it twice .. check updated answer

Comment: throws exception "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.'

Comment: okay, check updated answer.. just open connection like `connection.Open();`

Comment: sorry last question and I'm researching before I ask, but now I get invalid column name.

Comment: `col1` must be same name as you table column name .

Comment: Thank you I had an ID field which I created a new database without it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`table` is a reserved keyword in SQL including MSSQL.

- See all reserved keywords: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/reserved-keywords?view=sql-server-ver15

Below code could work, but I strongly recommend not to use reserved keyword for a table name. (related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/695626/361100 )

```cs
cmd.CommandText = ("insert into [table] values ('"+txtFirstName.Text+"', '"+txtLastName.Text+"', '"+txtAddress.Text+"'))");
```

Comment: I created new table called Member. Still getting error: updated code cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Member] values ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "', '" + txtAddress.Text + "')";

Comment: Does it say "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'"? If so you are not running the new code.

Answer (score 0):

The error is general because it is not able to understand the '[Member]' in your code. It seems suspicious in [Member]. Your table name is **Table**, but you cannot use it since it is a reserved keyword. Try writing this way.

```
private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Member("FirstName","LastName","Address") values ('" + txtFirstName.Text + "', '" + txtLastName.Text + "', '" + txtAddress.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Member added successfully");
    }
```

**Note:** The **("FirstName","LastName","Address")** are your table fields. Make sure your **Table** matches the cases (upper and lower) with that of your database table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There has been some confusion her @Rohan_Rao because the OP has edited the code from 'table' to 'member' after it was pointed out that 'table' is a reserved word. (By which your solution would fail too).

Comment: @TomC Got it. Thanks for pointing out. I have changed the table name to Member.